# Ionic collection-repeat missing most of array items

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I was using ng-repeat directive to show a huge list in my ionic app and recently switched to collection-repeat. However with collection repeat list got pretty short and it does not show all the array items. In code I only change collection-repeat to ng-repeat and it works just as expected. Btw I am trying to use it in a directive definition which is angucomplete and in directive I customly filter data here is the relevant html and js:

```
'<div class="angucomplete-holder">'+
                    '<input id="{{id}}_value" ng-model="searchStr" type="text" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" class="{{inputClass}}" onmouseup="this.select();" ng-focus="resetHideResults()"  />'+
                    '<ion-scroll direction="y" id="{{id}}_dropdown" class="angucomplete-dropdown" ng-if="showDropdown">'+
                        '<div class="angucomplete-searching" ng-show="searching">Searching...</div>'+
                        '<div class="angucomplete-searching" ng-show="!searching && (!results || results.length == 0)">No results found</div>'+
                        '<div class="angucomplete-searching" ng-show="!searching && (!results || results.length == 0)">{{noResultMsg}}</div>'+
                        '<div class="angucomplete-searching" ng-show="!searching && (!results || results.length == 0)"><img src="img/title_icon.png" style="width:30px;height:30px;"/></div>'+
                        '<div class="angucomplete-row" collection-repeat="result in results track by $index" ng-mousedown="selectResult(result)" ng-class="{\'angucomplete-selected-row\': $index == currentIndex}">'+
                            '<div ng-if="imageField" class="angucomplete-image-holder">'+
                                '<img ng-if="result.image && result.image != \'\'" ng-src="{{result.image}}" class="angucomplete-image"/>'+
                                '<div ng-if="!result.image && result.image != \'\'" class="angucomplete-image-default"></div>'+
                            '</div>'+
                            '<div class="angucomplete-title" ng-if="matchClass" ng-bind-html="result.title"></div>'+
                            '<div class="angucomplete-title" ng-if="!matchClass">{{ result.title }}</div>'+
                            '<div ng-if="result.description && result.description != \'\'" class="angucomplete-description">{{result.description}}</div>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</ion-scroll>'+
                '</div>',
```

and here is the js:

```
isNewSearchNeeded = function(newTerm, oldTerm) {
                return newTerm.length >= $scope.minLength && newTerm != oldTerm
            }

            $scope.processResults = function(responseData, str) {
                if (responseData && responseData.length > 0) {
                    $scope.results = [];

                    var titleFields = [];
                    if ($scope.titleField && $scope.titleField != "") {
                        titleFields = $scope.titleField.split(",");
                    }

                    for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
                        // Get title variables
                        var titleCode = [];

                        for (var t = 0; t < titleFields.length; t++) {
                            titleCode.push(responseData[i][titleFields[t]]);
                        }

                        var description = "";
                        if ($scope.descriptionField) {
                            description = responseData[i][$scope.descriptionField];
                        }

                        var imageUri = "";
                        if ($scope.imageUri) {
                            imageUri = $scope.imageUri;
                        }

                        var image = "";
                        if ($scope.imageField) {
                            image = imageUri + responseData[i][$scope.imageField];
                        }

                        var text = titleCode.join(' ');
                        if ($scope.matchClass) {
                            var re = new RegExp(str, 'i');
                            var strPart = text.match(re)[0];
                            text = $sce.trustAsHtml(text.replace(re, '<span class="'+ $scope.matchClass +'">'+ strPart +'</span>'));
                        }

                        var resultRow = {
                            title: text,
                            description: description,
                            image: image,
                            originalObject: responseData[i]
                        }

                        $scope.results[$scope.results.length] = resultRow;
                    }


                } else {
                    $scope.results = [];
                }
            }

            $scope.searchTimerComplete = function(str) {
                // Begin the search

                if (str.length >= $scope.minLength) {
                    if ($scope.localData) {
                        var searchFields = $scope.searchFields.split(",");

                        var matches = [];

                        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.localData.length; i++) {
                            var match = false;

                            for (var s = 0; s < searchFields.length; s++) {
                                match = match || (typeof $scope.localData[i][searchFields[s]] === 'string' && typeof str === 'string' && $scope.localData[i][searchFields[s]].toLowerCase().indexOf(str.toLowerCase()) >= 0);
                            }

                            if (match) {
                                matches[matches.length] = $scope.localData[i];
                            }
                        }

                        $scope.searching = false;
                        $scope.processResults(matches, str);

                    } else {
                        $http.get($scope.url + str, {}).
                            success(function(responseData, status, headers, config) {
                                $scope.searching = false;
                                $scope.processResults((($scope.dataField) ? responseData[$scope.dataField] : responseData ), str);
                            }).
                            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                                console.log("error");
                            });
                    }
                }
            }

            $scope.hideResults = function() {
                $scope.hideTimer = $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.showDropdown = false;
                }, $scope.pause);
            };

            $scope.resetHideResults = function() {
                if($scope.hideTimer) {
                    $timeout.cancel($scope.hideTimer);
                };
            };

            $scope.hoverRow = function(index) {
                $scope.currentIndex = index;
            }

            $scope.keyPressed = function(event) {
                if (!(event.which == 38 || event.which == 40 || event.which == 13)) {
                    if (!$scope.searchStr || $scope.searchStr == "") {
                        $scope.showDropdown = false;
                        $scope.lastSearchTerm = null
                    } else if (isNewSearchNeeded($scope.searchStr, $scope.lastSearchTerm)) {
                        $scope.lastSearchTerm = $scope.searchStr
                        $scope.showDropdown = true;
                        $scope.currentIndex = -1;
                        $scope.results = [];

                        if ($scope.searchTimer) {
                            $timeout.cancel($scope.searchTimer);
                        }

                        $scope.searching = true;

                        $scope.searchTimer = $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.searchTimerComplete($scope.searchStr);
                        }, $scope.pause);
                    }
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }

            $scope.selectResult = function(result) {
                if ($scope.matchClass) {
                    result.title = result.title.toString().replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, '');
                }
                $scope.searchStr = $scope.lastSearchTerm = result.title;
                $scope.selectedObject = result.title;
                $scope.showDropdown = false;
                $scope.results = [];
                //$scope.$apply();
            }

            var inputField = elem.find('input');

            inputField.on('keyup', $scope.keyPressed);

            elem.on("keyup", function (event) {
                if(event.which === 40) {
                    if ($scope.results && ($scope.currentIndex + 1) < $scope.results.length) {
                        $scope.currentIndex ++;
                        $scope.$apply();
                        event.preventDefault;
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }

                    $scope.$apply();
                } else if(event.which == 38) {
                    if ($scope.currentIndex >= 1) {
                        $scope.currentIndex --;
                        $scope.$apply();
                        event.preventDefault;
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }

                } else if (event.which == 13) {
                    if ($scope.results && $scope.currentIndex >= 0 && $scope.currentIndex < $scope.results.length) {
                        $scope.selectResult($scope.results[$scope.currentIndex]);
                        $scope.$apply();
                        event.preventDefault;
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    } else {
                        $scope.results = [];
                        $scope.$apply();
                        event.preventDefault;
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }

                } else if (event.which == 27) {
                    $scope.results = [];
                    $scope.showDropdown = false;
                    $scope.$apply();
                } else if (event.which == 8) {
                    $scope.selectedObject = null;
                    $scope.$apply();
                }
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks...